# Rabbit MQ - why my setup not provide messages to all clients?

Tags: java, ruby, jruby, rabbitmq

I have code in JRuby:

```
class Receiver

  def initialize(channel_id)
    @channel_id = channel_id

    factory = ConnectionFactory.new
    factory.setHost("localhost")
    connection = factory.newConnection
    @channel = connection.createChannel
    @channel.exchangeDeclare(exchange_name, "direct");
    @channel.queueDeclare(queue_name, true, false, false, nil)
    @channel.queueBind(queue_name, exchange_name, routing_key)
    @consumer = QueueingConsumer.new(@channel);
    @channel.basicConsume(queue_name, true, @consumer);
  end

  def receive
    String.from_java_bytes @consumer.nextDelivery.getBody
  end

  private

  def queue_name
    @channel_id
  end

  def exchange_name
    @channel_id
  end

  def routing_key
    @channel_id
  end

end
```

This code is responsible for getting messages in my architecture. However, when I have ie. two instances of `Receiver` with the same channel_id (which is basically exchange name, and route key) when I send message to this exchange one message goes to one receiver, one to another. Why, what I do wrong?

Comment: If you're using JRuby and RabbitMQ have a look at HotBunnies: https://rubygems.org/gems/hot_bunnies it's an abstraction on top of the Java RabbitMQ driver.

Comment: I checked it, but I have some problems. My usecase is quite uniqe - I need to send only one message for each connection and it was easier to  do it on top java library.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The question is why do you want to have something acted on by 2 agents simultaneously subscribed to a single queue?  Generally in RabbitMQ, multiple agents can be subscribed to one queue but they all do the same thing and it is for redundancy/load balancing purposes. A random agent picks up the message from the queue and ACKs it which then clears it from being consumed by anyone else.

Usually a queue implies one action and the agents listening are equivalent and can pick up on the message.  If you want to have a message go to one place then get broadcasted to multiple agents, it is preferable to use a *fanout* exchange and have each agent listen on a separate queue.

So think of each queue as if it were doing one thing. The behavior you are describing is exactly what is intended.

Please see [this tutorial](http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-three-java.html) for details on setting up a fanout exchange and what the different exchanges do.

Comment: I know fanout pattern. But I know what is wrong here, why messages deliveried to exchange dont go to each consumer registered to it?

Comment: Your consumers are not registered to an exchange, they are registered to queues.  The queues work exactly how queues do, first in first out.  If you have 2 consumers registered to one queue they will not both get the message, the first to ACK will.  Queues are registered to exchanges.  To obtain your desired behavior you will need a fan out exchange with 2 queues registered to it, with a consumer on each queue.

Comment: The fanout exchange does NOT fan out to consumers, it fans out to queues.  You have a single queue with 2 consumers on it.